# How to make streamwriter make a new line after specific number of integers?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I have file with 1000 random numbers (10 characters long) numbers and i want to create new txt file that will have 10 of these numbers on line and then make a new line with another 10 numbers.

I was only able to either print them all on first line or make a line after every (10) numbers.

```
        {
            string path = @"textasd.txt";
            string ro = @"nums.dat";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ro);
            int length = 0,c;
            char[] field= new char[10];
            while ((c = sr.Read()) != -1)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit((char)c))
                {
                    pole[length] = (char)c;
                    length++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(length >= 5)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(field, 0, length);
                    }
                    length = 0;
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writeline` always writes into new line. You need to use `Write` and have a `WriteLine` when 10 numbers already written.

```
{
    string path = @"textasd.txt";
    string ro = @"nums.dat";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ro);
    int length = 0,c;
    char[] field= new char[10];
    var numbersProcessed = 0;  //----> this is new
    while ((c = sr.Read()) != -1)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit((char)c))
        {
            field[length] = (char)c;
            length++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(length >= 5)
            {
                //---> new code starts
                numbersProcessed++;
                sw.Write(field, 0, length);
                if (numbersProcessed % 10 == 0)
                {
                     sw.WriteLine();
                }
                //---> new code ends
            }
            length = 0;
        }
    }
    sr.Close();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! (only had to add space after 'sw.Write(field, 0, length);' to split the numbers but i didnt specify this).